# unable to update to new version of my Google Script

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script

I have written a script to upload a file in google Drive with a html form.

My first version was only with this code:

```
<input type="file" name="theFile">
   <input type="hidden" name="anExample">
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run.serverFunc(this.parentNode)">
```

Later I added new components:

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
   <label>Responsabile:</label> 
   <select name="resp"> 
   <option value="user1@elyspa.it">1</option> 
   <option value="user2@elyspa.it">2</option>
   <option value="user3@elyspa.it">3</option>
   </select>
   <p>Totale €: <input type="Text" name="tot"></p>
   <input type="file" name="theFile">
   <input type="hidden" name="anExample">
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run.serverFunc(this.parentNode)">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I published the new application but I cannot see the new one, I continue to see the older page.
I tried also to unpublish the project and publish it again... Nothing. I continue to see the older page...

Please, someone could help me.

Thanks

..............................

```
code.gs:
// Script-as-app template.
function doGet() {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page.html');
}

function serverFunc(theForm) {
   var now = new Date();
   var datetime = Utilities.formatDate(now, "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd");
   var utente = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
   var utenteorig = utente;
   utente = utente.replace("@elyspa.it", "");
   utente = utente.replace(".", "_");
   var prefix = 'NotaSpese-';
   var name = prefix + utente + '_' + datetime;
   var folderName = '01_NoteSpese';
   var anExampleText = theForm.anExample;  // This is a string
   var fileBlob = theForm.theFile;         // This is a Blob.
   var totale = theForm.tot;
   var resp = theForm.resp;
   Logger.log(name)
   fileBlob.setName(name);
   var approvalsSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AmlI-G8XpXeQdDNXYzNtbEQ3YTdQMmQxX1RsYTNaZ0E");
   var approvalsSheet = approvalsSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
   approvalsSheet.appendRow([datetime, utenteorig, totale, resp]);

   /*var exist = checkFolder(folderName);
  if(exist){
    var folder = DocsList.getFolder(folderName);
    var adoc = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
  }
  else{
    var folder = DocsList.createFolder(folderName);
    var adoc = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
  }*/

  var folder = DocsList.getFolder(folderName);
  var adoc = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
  Logger.log(adoc.getUrl())  
  Logger.log(name)
  return adoc.getUrl();
}

function checkFolder(folderName){
  var exist = true;
  try{var testFolder = DocsList.getFolder(folderName)}
  catch(err){exist=false}
  return exist;
}
```

Comment: could you please also show the server code (gs file) ? thanks.

Comment: more info: if i open the ".../dev" link all is ok but if I open the shared link with ".../exec" I see old code...

Answer (score 0):

You have to save a new version (file menu in script editor) and then go to "publish" and from there select the right version to publish.

This feature has been developed to allow you to work on a code while it is already published without compromising its functionality. One can publish online only stable versions and keep working on the "dev" version.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I have undertand the versioning... Now a user in my domain cannot use the script (you don't have permission). I set the permission: anyone in my organization can visualize... Why when the user opens the page with embedded the script he see the page to request authorization?

Comment: are you sure he logs in with his domain account ? sometimes people are logged with many different accounts. That said you don't have to share the script to allow users to use the app, these are 2 complete different sharing setups.

Comment: I'm logged in with his account... At the moment I cannot modify the projrct again.... I have created a new version and deleted the older, then i published the new code in the new version.... But I continue to see the older one... :(

Comment: In attach the screenshot with different behavior... https://www.dropbox.com/s/iy8pirvgtn6nzfn/Pictures.zip
USER: white page (cannot open the script)
OWNER - me: output of the script
POLICY: published policies

Why is there this different "point of view"?

Comment: Solved partially.... The problem is Firefox... maybe the html is not well formed.
Which html tags have I to add in google script? from <HTML> or from <body>?

Thanks